# How much does model rocketry prepare for an actual career in rocket design?

Tags: model-rocketry, education

I have been doing model rocketry for years, both the premade kits from Estes (and others), and doing scratch design as well. Some of these have been successes, and others, well, not so much.

I have read some small tracts on design, fin shapes, determining center of gravity, other basic concepts, and I was wondering about it, since I have small children that I will introduce to the hobby as well.

If someone is interested in going into the rocket/space exploration industry, what aspects of model rocketry would be of the most benefit in translation?

Comment: I'm interested in this question, to the point that I started writing an answer, but in the process, I became convinced that it's an opinion-based question.  If there's a way to reword it so that it can get a quantifiable answer, that would be awesome.

Comment: @OrganicMarble - I reworded, better?

Comment: The math and the physics transfer more than anything else.  If you can teach them an intuition for the aerodynamics and thermodynamics, that would be sufficient.

Comment: I was way into model rocketry for a long time, then I joined the Marines and started dealing with guided anti tank missiles. Liquid helium lubricated gyroscopic stabilizers, argon gas coolant systems, explosive squib motivated actuators etc etc. Prior to that I THOUGHT I knew a lot about rocketry, turns out I knew pretty much next to nothing compared to systems of that complexity.